# Data Loading using Flink efficiency?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I am working on getting various approaches to load data at once from One Database to Another. It may / may not be NoSQL or SQL or RDBMS. I am thinking about how efficiently can Flink execute sink and source.
Can Flink do the data loading less than 50% vs the traditional Data Loading methods ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be limited by the available disk i/o and network bandwidth. Just depends on how much throughput the data stores can support.